# Kafka connect is not consuming data continuously

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

[image]

As shown in the attached diagram Kafka Connect is consuming data only every 5 mins, any idea how to fix this and ensure continuous consumption.

Comment: Need more details. It is continous. It's just not flat... Is your producer continous? If there's zero lag, then the byte rate will go to zero

Comment: Yes, the producer is continuous & the topic has lag build up since the consumption is not continuous.

Comment: But **it is** "continuous". `max.poll.records` defaults to 500 records per poll. There is also `max.poll.interval.ms` that defaults the time between two polls. In addition to that, there are other network request timeouts... I suggest you create another panel for consumer lag